# Do java annotations only apply to the property directly underneath it?

Tags: java, annotations

Lets say I have something like

```
class Example
{
    @MyCustomAnnotation
    private int property_1;
    private int property_2;

    private int property_3;
}
```

Does `@MyCustomAnnotation` apply to `property_1 & property_2` attributes or just `property_1`?

If the latter, is there any way to make @MyCustomAnnotation apply to both `property_1 & property_2` but not `property_3`? (e.g. everything below it terminating at `\n`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does @MyCustomAnnotation apply to property_1 & property_2 attributes

No.

> or just property_1?

Yes.

> If the latter, is there any way to make @MyCustomAnnotation apply to both property_1 & property_2 but not property_3?

No.

> (e.g. everything below it terminating at \n)

`\n` isn't significant to the parser.

You can't just make up your own rules. Annotations apply to the declaration they are annotating.